# Unable to iterate Promise values from a fetch request

Tags: javascript, php, fetch-api

I have a simple fetch request in JavaScript:

```
async function getItems(url){
try {
    return await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {return data});
} catch(e) {
}
```

In another function I have:

```
const items = getItems(url);
console.log(items);

const items = await getItems(url);
```

The response I get is:

```
Promise { "fulfilled" }
<state>: "fulfilled"
<value>: Array(13) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
```

So, that means that I get my values. They are located in the promise in the `<value>`. When I try to iterate through the items with:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    html += '<option value="'+items[i].id +'">' + items[i].name +'</option>'
}
```

Nothing happens. So, when I do `console.log(items.length)`, I get that the length is `undefined`.
This might sound stupid and Iäm fairly new to JavaScript, but how can I iterate through the  array so that I can build my HTML?
Here are the sources I've read in order to try and resolved this without any help, so this is why I asked:

- [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516390/how-to-access-the-value-of-a-promise)
- [How to get data returned from fetch() promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604040/how-to-get-data-returned-from-fetch-promise/47604112)
- [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)
- [JS Fetch API access return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417982/js-fetch-api-access-return-value)
- [Resolve promises in iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253452/resolve-promises-in-iteration)

EDIT: The mistake was here:

```
const items = getItems(url);
```

I needed to add the await call:

Comment: `getItems()` is marked as `async`, hence it will return a `Promise`

Comment: There's no need for `async/await` in your example. Simply `return fetch(...).then(response => response.json())` + [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: As @Andreas mentioned, the issue is not with the fetch call, but the `getItems(url)` call itself. Since the method is async we should be calling it with an await keyword like below.

```js
const items = await getItems(url);
```

---

Since you are returning the fetch call, it will return a promise. Rather you should be returning the data that you parse from the json response.

Try this

```js
async function getItems(url){
try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
} catch(e) {
}
```

Comment: _"Since you are returning the fetch call..."_ - No, OP returns the result of the last `.then()` wrapped in a `Promise`

Comment: Yea, I actually tried this, I should've mentioned it earlier, sorry, but it's still returning the same thing.

Comment: I missed the 'await' call. That was stupid of me.

Comment: If the answer helps, kindly mark it as accepted :) @BuscusDude

Comment: I can in 1 muinute, it doesn't let me :D